# Unable to Access a website using FirefoxDriver and HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, htmlunit-driver

I'm trying to access the website using FirefoxDriver but I'm getting a ***not a valid url exception***

I also tried with HtmlUnitDriver there the website title come back as ***null***

I tied the old and new website on the below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Family\\path to firefox driver\\geckodriver.exe");

//WebDriver driver = HtmlUnitDriver();

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

//this is an old website
//driver.get("https://www.hollywoodbets.net");

//this is a new website
driver.get("https://new.hollywoodbets.net");

System.out.println("WEBSITE TITTLE " + driver.getTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are trying to open blocks access to it for Chrome too.
I tried to open it with regular Chrome browser on my PC even without Selenium.
It presents the following message:

> Error 1020 Ray ID: 6d9bdf8b1b729131 • 2022-02-07 10:18:16 UTC
> Access denied
> What happened?
> This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.

> Cloudflare Ray ID: 6d9bdf8b1b729131 • Your IP: 77.137.69.164 • Performance & security by Cloudflare

Occurs both for `https://new.hollywoodbets.net` and for `https://www.hollywoodbets.net`.  The former link is actually redirecting to the first one.

Comment: I'm able to open both websites using a normal browser both Firefox and Chrome both on mobile devices and desktop. Maybe on your site it because you accessing outside of the country South Africa.

Comment: Maybe. I'm not from the SA.

Comment: What could be the possible problem not able to access the website?

Comment: Are you getting `not a valid url exception` error?

Comment: Yes, with FirefoxDriver and with HtmlUnitDriver the website title come back as null.

Comment: That's strange since the `URL` itself appears to be correct

Comment: Maybe they using a security service to prevent automaton on their website. Please recomend someone who can answer.

Comment: As you can see in my answer, the page is blocked by `Cloudflare` at least from my country. I guess it block bots from the local IP addresses as well.